# footer wont align or work properly

Tags: html, css

I have two different page styles, one on my index with a huge "picture" and the other style is the main one i use wich dont contain a "picture".

first design was taken from `codepen.io/jeffbredenkamp/pen/ZpGOAW` and have only had a few things removed (barely anything but nothing import like `height` or `margin`).

The problem is my footer is stupid and on the index it ends up inside the `header` (picture from link above) even tho it got content under it. While on the other pages the footer is stuck to the bottom (how i want it) but when i zoom it goes over the other content.

I am not able to share all the code because it for some reason display it differently on codepin.io but i have shared the `footer`, `footer.css`, and the style for my `.tabs` (.tabs is the other content that my footer moves above when zoom)

*Edit: I have been able to place everything into codepen.io . i huge mess with the css as there is 4 different css files combined but you can have a look here:

Style 1: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjmZzy
Style 2: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKvEPy
footer:

```
<div style="padding:30px;"></div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="banner">
        <a href=""><img src="/assets/images/templates/footer-banner.png" class="banner"/></a>
    </div>

    <div class="item i1">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <div class="p">
            about information.
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="item i2">
        <h1>Help</h1>
        <div class="p">
            You can find a help page<a href="/help" class="footer-link">here</a>.
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="item i3">
        <h1>Server</h1>
        <div class="p">
            server information<br />
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="host">
        <img src="" class="host" />
    </div>


    <div class="footer-bottom">
        <div class="fl">
            <a class="footer-link" href="/help">Help</a>    |
            <a class="footer-link" href="/#about">About</a> |
            <a class="footer-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </div>

        <div class="fr" style="padding-right:10px;">&copy; Copyright <?php echo $domain; ?> | 2015 - <?php echo date("Y") ?></div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

footer.css:

```
.footer {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#23282c;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

    min-height:150px;
    height: auto !important; /* This line and the next line are not necessary unless you need IE6 support */

}

.footer-bottom {
    background-color:#1e2327;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:25px;
    color:#777f8c;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

    height:25px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:9;
}

.banner {
    width:35%;
    margin-left:10px;
    line-height:160px;
    padding:7px;
    float:left;
}

.item {
    position:relative;
}

.i1 {
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    padding-top:7px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    padding-right:190px;
    font-size:15px;
}

.i2 {
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    padding-top:7px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    padding-right:190px;
    font-size:15px;
}

.i3 {
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    padding-top:7px;
    margin-left:-150px;
    padding-right:190px;
    font-size:15px;
}

.item h1 {
    color:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #475f93;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:left;
}

.item .p {
    color:#777f8c;
}

.footer-link {
    color:#777f8c;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.footer-link:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
```

.tabs:

```
<div class="tabs" id="about">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <div class="p">
            Welcome to <span><?php echo $address; ?></span> a website created by <span><?php echo $domain; ?></span>.<br />     
            Got any questions? Please contact us <br />
            <a href="/contact" class="contact-btn">Contact Us</a>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

.tabs css:

```
.tabs {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  width: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-height:120px;
  padding:7px;
  overflow:visible;
}
.tabs h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    color:#475f93;
    font-weight:400;
    border-bottom:1px solid #475f93;
}

.tabs .p {
    color:#121417;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: `The problem is my footer is stupid` - really? Can you create a small sample of the problem - no one is going to wade through this spaghetti

Comment: It might not have been that clear but the problem is that on page 1 where i uses a "picture" (http://codepen.io/jeffbredenkamp/pen/ZpGOAW) the footer display at the bottom of the "picture" and not the page. the problem is caused by the `<header>` tag, but im not able to fix it

Comment: Add a `clear: both;` on `footer` and check if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `position` in your `.footer` to `position: relative;` and remove the `margin-bottom: -142px;` of your `.wrapper`.

```
.footer {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#23282c;

    position: relative;

    min-height:150px;
    height: auto !important; /* This line and the next line are not necessary unless you need IE6 support */

}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

PS.: You don't really need to do `<footer class="footer">`, you can just use `<footer>` and target it in your CSS using `footer` instead of `.footer`.

Comment: nope nothing.
but by making `.footer` `position:relative;` it then forces it to the bottom of the page so atleast one problem solved. now im just left with the problem where my footer moves above the `.tabs` on zoom instead of making the page longer

how it looks now http://imgur.com/miSyXoP
how i want it to look http://imgur.com/nRazbI6

Comment: That's right, I was about to tell you about the `position` issue.

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot to remove the original `.wrapper`, works now. but could you have a look why my `.footer-bottom` is not 100% at the bottom?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAZqZm

Comment: That's because you have the `line-height:160px;` in `.banner`. Remove it and you are good to go: http://codepen.io/wmerussi/pen/RGWjNp. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it's what you are looking for.

Comment: I have updated the `.footer-bottom` to be `display:inline-block;`. this is to prevent the text in the footer from disapearing when i zoom.

I am not able to get it to work by changing the line-height in `.banner`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKjOvJ

Comment: This answer has answered your question, you need to open a new question to check other parts of your code otherwise this one will just continue forever until you have your complete website.